# Variable this has different context in error handling (catchSubscriber)

Tags: angular, ionic2, this

I've looked a bit around, but coudn't find a solution for my issue.

Situation:

I have a DataProvider that handles all the GET-requests to the server and handles the errors. When an error occurs, a method is called that invokes the AlertController of Ionic 2.

The problem is that I can't access said method because this has a different context.
It probably has to do with the chaining when creating the GET-request.

It seems like `bind` can solve this problem, but I can't figure out how to implement it in this situation.

```
export class DataProvider 
{
  constructor(public http     : Http,
              public alertCtrl: AlertController) 
  {

  }
  getArticles(): Promise<any> 
  {  
    return this.createHttpRequestGet(this.baseUrl + 'beProduct');  
  }

  private createHttpRequestGet(url: string) : Promise<any>
  {
    return this.http.get(url, this.getRequestOptions()).map((response) => response.json()).timeout(7500).catch(this.handleError).toPromise();
  }

  private handleError(error:any) 
  {
    var message = { title: "", text: "" }   

    switch (error.status)
    {
      case 401:
        // Unauthorized
        message.title = "..."
        message.text = "... (" + error.status + ").";        
        break;

    ...      
    }        
    // Can't access variable this
    this.showErrorAlertText(error.title, error.message);
    return Promise.reject(message);
  }

  showErrorAlertText(title: string, message: string)
  {
    this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: title,
      subTitle: message,
      buttons: ['Ok']
    }).present();
  }
}
```

This is the value of this before executing `this.showErrorAlertText(..,..)`
[image]

Comment: Where/How do you use this provider?

Comment: I actually don't use typescript so I will comment instead of answer. Have you tried creating a self variable and assign it in the contructor: `var self = this;`? If you want to stick with bind try adding one here: `return this.http.get(url, this.getRequestOptions()).bind(this).map(...).toPromise();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
.catch(error => this.handleError(error))
```

**Option 2:**
(Assuming you use TypeScript)

```
private handleError = (error:any) => {
  var message = { title: "", text: "" }
```

**Option 3:**

```
.catch(this.handleError.bind(this))
```

Comment: Thanks! Using option 1 it works now. I don't really jnow why it does acutally. Didn't release this syntax work different internally

Comment: @Matt Arrow functions (=>) preserve the value of `this`.

Comment: I assumed catch(this.handleError) did the same thing as using fat arrows. Because it did pass the errror automatically.